# mysql pick up a random entry selected from certain criterial

Tags: mysql

I want sort one user from table who never had a note different from 0
then update the record,
then insert a new row

```
  user  note
  12      1
  23      0
  88      0
  45      0
  12      0
  23      0
  12      0
  88      2
```

sort a user except user 12 and user 88 becouse the have already a note somewhere
somethink like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE note=0 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

the problem is that i've many users duplicate so i dont know how to exlude that...
let's say that i randomly choose the user 23
the table should become

```
  user  note
  12      1
  23      0
  88      0
  45      0
  12      0
  23      X    <--- mark the random user choosen
  12      0
  88      2
  23      0    <--- add a new line
```

in the next random pick up only the number 45 will be avaiable becouse other user has somewhere a note != 0

for this last request i've to do 2 query UPDATE then INSERT or i can do with just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid subqueries for improved performance and go like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING SUM(note)=0 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

Here is an [**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7374c6/5).

Comment: doesnt work well, i try few times and it's pick up 88, i need to avoid pick up that this works: SELECT *
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(note)=0
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;

Comment: Why do you not want that? The picking is done randomly!

Comment: try to see it as lottery ticket bought by users, each user can buy many tickets, when the "note" field is setted means that user has won something.
Now i want pick up an extra random ticket just from the looser only from ppl who dint never won

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested select :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE note=0 and user not in (select user from table where note>0) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

however u should really use primary unique index on users

Comment: TNX works! if i have an huge table it's works too?
about index i've ID, about unique i can set it, becouse i need table with each user can set many entry.